# Command works in SSH via MobaXterm, but not found in SSH via PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh, phpseclib

I'm trying to connect to a server in my PHP code via SSH (using the Net_SSH2 class), and run a number of commands on the remote server.

The remote server outputs `bash: runmqsc: command not found`.

The odd thing is, that the exact same command is found and functional on that server, when I SSH to it using MobaXterm.

I validated that the code uses the correct hostname, user and password to connect.

Any ideas?

This is what I'm doing in PHP:

```
$this->ssh = new Net_SSH2("myhost");
$this->ssh->login("myuser", "mypass");

$command = "runmqsc MyQmgr \n DEFINE QLOCAL(MY_QUEUE) \n end \n";
$this->ssh->exec($command);
```

Comment: Do the `myuser` shell startup scripts set `PATH`, etc. to allow that to work? Because `Net_SSH2` is may not be starting an interactive session that loads those.

Comment: @EtanReisner If that's the case, than why does this work via MobaXterm?

Comment: Because that **is** starting an interactive session.

Comment: Do you mean that Moba reads a file somewhere and sets PATH accordingly? If so where is that file located?

Comment: No. MobaXterm runs an interactive shell session. Your shell then reads the startup scripts appropriate for an interactive session. Those scripts likely set the `$PATH`. `Net_SSH2` is likely **not** starting an interactive session and so those don't get loaded. Look at `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something more like this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("runmqsc MyQmgr\n"); // note the "\n"
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$'); // or whatever the prompt is - does runmqsc have it's own prompt?
$ssh->write("DEFINE QLOCAL(MY_QUEUE)\n");
?>
```

...etc...